# My LI takes up the initial image width of 500px while i set the picture width to 10%

Tags: html, css

My `<li>` takes up the initial image width of 500px while i set the picture width to 10%. Code below:

```css
header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li a {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a><img id="navLogo" src="http://placekitten.com/800/800"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

It's probably something very simple but I just want the `<li>` to fit the image width. Picture of the `<li>` in google chrome:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is and what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix is to use a `px` value instead of a `%` value here.  I'm not entirely sure why... but this fixes the main issue here.

I took your code and did this as well as made some other simplifications so there's just less code to do the same thing.  Comments are added by each change.

```css
header nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #CCC; /* Added so we can see the text */
  align-items: center; /* Added to vertically center all the items*/
}

header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px; /* Added to space out items*/
}

#navLogo {
  display: block; /* Added remove extra space below image */
  width: 30px; /* Use a px value instead of % to avoid spacing issues */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#"><img id="navLogo" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300"></a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Blogs</a>
    <a href="#">Education</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

I found the problem is here. Then I change the code like:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This shows that the problem is gone!